# Change UIBarButtonItem into Simple Icon

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to display the "settings gear" instead of the word "Settings" in by navigation bar. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settingsAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no default way to get this image. You should use `initWithImage:style:target:action:`
and add an image of your own. You can make one yourself, or get pre-rolled from some where like Glyphish: http://www.glyphish.com

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a UIButton first , setting the gear image on it and than

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```